# PHP & JQuery Question

Tags: php, jquery

I was wondering lets say I have a form that you can save and preview changes before you save the changes, what will be the best way to preview the changes in a different page, the same page or a lightbox? Can you give me some live examples if possible?

Comment: depends on the type of changes you will do, could you give an example?

Comment: change of text and images like in the about me page for example.

Comment: would call a ligthbox like this "http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/" for example with data before recording, and there I would put the final Save button

Comment: Seems more like a User Experience question for the UI stackexchange site rather than SO.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know much about jquery lightbox and other fancy stuff but one way of doing this is the way people create their print pages. i.e: select a portion of a page and display it in popup window with printer friendly styles. u can also show form data in popup window with save and cancel buttons. pressing those buttons will return control to ur parent window where u can decide whether u should post the form for saving to db